# How can I can the integer value (range 0-255) of a grayscale image pixel

Tags: c#

Hi I want to get the integer values (0-255 range) of a gray scale image ....this code shows me the R,G,B values not one value..how can i get it?

```
Bitmap temp1 = image1;
for (int i = 0; i < temp1.Height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < temp1.Width; j++)
    {
        Color cl = new Color();
        cl = temp1.GetPixel(i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's a (true) gray, the R, G and B values will be the same, you can pick any one of them

Comment: There are different sorts of grey, the easiest certainly all 3 values equal. The human eye perceives colors differently. Some programs optimize for human eyes. In that case, the 3 values may differ

Answer (score 1):

If your source image is greyscale and you just want the level of greyness, just pick any of the three components. They will be equal.

If your source image is color but you want to get the grey equivalent, you can convert your color to a grey value in the range 0..255 by blending the red, green and blue color components together. The blending factors are different because the human eye has different sensitivity to the three primary colors. For fun, try varying the factors (e.g. use 0.3333 for each) and see what the result looks like.

```
Color cl = c.GetPixel(i, j); // No need to separately allocate a new Color()
int greyValue = (int)((cl.R * 0.3) + (cl.G * 0.59) + (cl.B * 0.11));
Color grey = Color.FromArgb(cl.A, greyValue, greyValue, greyValue);
```

Note that it is quite slow to loop through a larger Bitmap, using GetPixel() on each pixel. There are much faster techniques available.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Here's an example image with different scaling factors for R, G, and B applied. The image will always be greyscaled because the same numeric value is used for each RGB component in the modified image, but the relative lightness does change. The middle image uses scaling factors suitable for the human eye. Note how blue areas in the original image seem oversaturated in the rightmost version.

Comment: Where did you get those scaling factors (0.3, 0.59, and 0.11)?

Comment: It's been a while so I don't recall the exact source, but they're based on the human eye's relative ability to perceive red, green, and blue. Note that any chosen parameters will still give you a black-and-white image because you'll use the "grey" value for each component (r,g,b) in the new image, but the relative brightness will vary. For fun, I applied different scaling factors to an image and updated the question with it.

Answer (score 1):

just read the properties R or G or B, any of them will have the same value.

```
var intValue = cl.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get grayscale from RGB. 
A common way is to do (R+G+B)/3
Others are computing some luminance Luminance measure (Lab, YUV, HSV)