# How can I properly convert Bitmap RGB color to a 2d double array?

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

I needed to convert a `Bitmap` image to a 2D `double` array.
I want an arbitrary number for each pixel that represents an RBG color scaled between 0-1.
I want to convert a Bitmap image into a 2D double array so that I can apply convolution operation to that Bitmap image. 
So, I have written the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("lena.jpg");

        pictureBox1.Image = image;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ToDataTable(ToDouble2d(image));
    }        

    public static double[,] ToDouble2d(Bitmap input)
    {
        int width = input.Width;
        int height = input.Height;

        double[,] array2d = new double[width, height];

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                Color clr = input.GetPixel(x, y);

                double iClr = (double)clr.ToArgb();

                array2d[x, y] = iClr / 255.0;
            }
        }

        return array2d;
    }

    public static DataTable ToDataTable(double[,] numbers)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Column" + (i + 1));
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(0); ++i)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            for (var j = 0; j < numbers.GetLength(1); ++j)
            {
                row[j] = numbers[i, j];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

[image]

First problem I notice is: all values are negative.
So, I tried to rescale them between `0` and `1`.

```
private static void Rescale(double[,] convolve)
{
    int imageWidth = convolve.GetLength(0);
    int imageHeight = convolve.GetLength(1);

    double maxAmp = 0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
        {
            maxAmp = Math.Max(maxAmp, convolve[i, j]);
        }
    }

    double scale = 1 / maxAmp;

    for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
        {
            double d = convolve[i, j] * scale;
            convolve[i, j] = d;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, all intensities have become `-Infinity`.

[image]

So, what is the proper way to handle this scenario?

**Note.** performance is not an issue at this point(e.g. Bitmap locking etc.). I just want to know why my code is not working, and how to do that properly.

Comment: So you want to get the hue-saturation-lightness (HSL) lightness value for a color?

Comment: Just the RGB, or alpha channel as well

Comment: It is normal that `ToArgb()` gives negative values; it is a `UInt32` that starts with the alpha value, which is generally 0xFF, but since it is represented as `Int32`, this means the first bit is enabled, ergo, the number is seen as negative. To get around that, just cast it to `UInt32` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have solved the problem from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38465006/159072).

```
    public static double[,] ToDouble2d(Bitmap input)
    {
        int width = input.Width;
        int height = input.Height;

        double[,] array2d = new double[width, height];

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                Color cl = input.GetPixel(x, y);

                // A 2d double data is always Grayscale.
                // So, three elements are averaged.
                double gray = ((cl.R * 0.3) + (cl.G * 0.59) + (cl.B * 0.11));

                array2d[x, y] = gray/255.0;
            }
        }

        return array2d;
    }
```

Comment: Well, your question doesn't even mention you wanted to treat it as grayscale. You could also just use the `GetBrightness()` value from the `Color`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, or why. However, if you just want an arbitrary number representing RBG values scaled from 0 to 1. You maybe able to do something like this

```
public static Uint RGBtoUInt(int r, int g, int b)
{
    return (uint)(( r << 0 ) | ( g << 8 ) | ( b << 16 ));
}

...

var myArbitaryValue = RGBtoInt(r,g,b) / (double)16581375; // maximum 24bit color value
```

**Note** : totally untested